# yaml format as request post body

Tags: python, json, request, yaml

i want to convert a post request body from json to yaml 
the origin json format is like this:

```
{
    "traceId": "1000000316028",
    "orderDto": {
        "totalPrice": "0.01",
        "baseList": [],
        "hongbaoSn": "",
        "couponSn": "",
        "shelfCode": "2SvNXIz56rL0EU5PpSpzwA..",
        "additionalPurchaseList": [],
        "bindingList": [{
            "baseSku": {
                "count": 1,
                "skuId": 1001088
            },
            "additionalSku": []
        }]
    }
}
```

and i convert it to yaml format like below:

```
traceId: 1000000316028
orderDto:
  totalPrice: 0.01
  baseList: []
  hongbaoSn:
  couponSn:
  shelfCode: 2SvNXIz56rL0EU5PpSpzwA..
  additionalPurchaseList: []
  bindingList:
  - baseSku: {count: 1, skuId: 1001088}
    addtionalSku: []
```

and put it as post body in python request, like this:

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

but it's wrong, response code is -1.
i copied from postman, the right body format is like that:

> data = "{\n\t\"traceId\": \"1000000316028\",\n\t\"orderDto\": {\n\t\t\"totalPrice\": \"0.01\",\n\t\t\"baseList\": [],\n\t\t\"hongbaoSn\": \"\",\n\t\t\"couponSn\": \"\",\n\t\t\"shelfCode\": \"2SvNXIz56rL0EU5PpSpzwA..\",\n\t\t\"additionalPurchaseList\": [],\n\t\t\"bindingList\": [{\n\t\t\t\"baseSku\": {\n\t\t\t\t\"count\": 1,\n\t\t\t\t\"skuId\": 1001088\n\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\"additionalSku\": []\n\t\t}]\n\t}\n}"

this can response code 200.

but where is wrong if i want to use yaml format?

thanks very much!

Comment: `data=json.dumps(data)` – this code is for JSON, not YAML.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i tried json.dumps(data) ,yaml.dump(data,Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper) and data is read from yaml. Both wrong. But if data is read from json, i use json.dump(data), it can response 200. i convert json to yaml online, so i don't know where is wrong

Answer (score 1):

solved.
i modified my yaml format as below:

```
traceId: '1000000316028'
orderDto:
  totalPrice: '0.01'
  baseList: []
  hongbaoSn: ''
  couponSn: ''
  shelfCode: 2SvNXIz56rL0EU5PpSpzwA..
  additionalPurchaseList: []
  bindingList:
  - baseSku:
      count: 1
      skuId: 1001088
    additionalSku: []
```